# How to change text after button click using Bloc flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

So I'm learning basics of bloc and I wanted to know how to change a text using a button without setstate(), this whole time ive been using setstate but I would like to know how to change a text after a button click using bloc, state, event.

This is what I have so far

Main.dart

```
    void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => SecscreenBloc(),
          ),

        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            onGenerateRoute: Routes().onGenerateRoute,
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: SecScreen()),
      );
  }
}
```

SecScreen.dart

```
class SecScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecScreen> createState() => _SecScreenState();
}

class _SecScreenState extends State<SecScreen> {
  var numm = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => SecscreenBloc()..add(LoadSecscreenEvent(numm)),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Bloc Increment"),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<SecscreenBloc,SecscreenState>(
          builder: (context,state){
            if(state is SecScreenLoadedState){
              return Column(
                children: [
                  Text("Activity:   ${state.number}"),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => BlocProvider.of<SecscreenBloc>(context).add(LoadSecscreenEvent(
                      numm
                    )),
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
            return Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

SecScreen_event.dart

```
abstract class SecscreenEvent extends Equatable {
  const SecscreenEvent();
}
class LoadSecscreenEvent extends SecscreenEvent{
  final int number;

  LoadSecscreenEvent(this.number);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [number];
}
```

SecScreen_state.dart

```
        part of 'secscreen_bloc.dart';

abstract class SecscreenState extends Equatable {
  const SecscreenState();
}

class SecscreenInitial extends SecscreenState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class SecScreenLoadedState extends SecscreenState{

  final int number;
  SecScreenLoadedState(this.number);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [number];
}
```

secscreen_bloc.dart

```
class SecscreenBloc extends Bloc<SecscreenEvent, SecscreenState> {
  SecscreenBloc() : super(SecscreenInitial()) {
    on<LoadSecscreenEvent>((event, emit) {
      if (event is LoadSecscreenEvent){
        emit(SecScreenLoadedState(event.number + 1));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I've been stuck at this for an embarssingly long time, would appreciate some help!

Comment: You already change a text of a `Text` depending on a value managed by the bloc. What is the problem changing the text of a button three lines below? What did you try? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i have updated my question to make it clearer, please have a check, i have a text and i would like this text to change into another text when a button is clicked using bloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it is changed every time you press but every time the value gone to the bloc 1 and back 2 so you did not see the effection

just change the following line

```
onPressed: () => BlocProvider.of<SecscreenBloc>(context).add(LoadSecscreenEvent(
                  numm
                )),
```

to this one :

```
 onPressed: () => BlocProvider.of<SecscreenBloc>(context)
                  .add(LoadSecscreenEvent(state.number)),
```

Comment: ahh this makes sense, it works now :) !